# ObservableCollection does not raise property changed with Fody

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

I have defined this class

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ChatInfo : IMessageData
{
    public ObservableCollection<Message> messages { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Message LastMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return messages.Last();
        }
    }
}
```

The class is deserialized via JSON.NET(James King) and then after I manually pushing new items to `messages`. The `LastMessage` property is bound to a view, but even if `messages` collection changes, `LastMessage` getter is not called. When I set `messages` to new collection every time, everything works fine, why doesn't `LastMessage` react to collection changed events from `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I'd doubt that Fody.PropertyChanged analyses the code and subscribes to `CollectionChanged`.  You'd have to do this yourself.

Comment: You may need to show your xaml code also, just to get an idea of ,how the view is informed when the message collection is changed ?

Next thing, if it's not written in your xaml code, you may have to manually raise the propertyChanged event for LastMessage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LastMessage does not react on collection change because message remain the same.
You need to subscribe to the event of your observable collection.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ChatInfo : IMessageData
{
  public ObservableCollection<Message> messages { get; set; }

  messages.CollectionChanged += new
  System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(MessageChanged);

  [JsonIgnore]
  public Message LastMessage {get; private set;}


  private void MessageChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) 
  {
   //set the property here
   LastMessage = messages.Last();
  }
}
```